# debian packaging and package.rules files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, ubuntu-16.04, packaging

I am  working on changing machines from the RHEL world over to the debian/ubuntu world, and I am struggling a bit with a packaging problem.  I am trying to build a package for Ubuntu 16.4.

I've got an very old pre-compiled application that can only listen through xinetd.  I am creating a binary only package similar to what this person was doing: [I need my Debian rules file to simply copy files to it's target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214319/i-need-my-debian-rules-file-to-simply-copy-files-to-its-target).  I simply need to copy pre-compiled files into directories.

I have no problem getting files in /opt and in /var/log, however I have been trying to get the dpkg to copy the needed setup file into /etc/xinetd.d/

So I have a debian/package.install file something like this:

```
opt/oldapplication-3.10/* opt/oldapplication-3.10/
var/log/* var/log/
etc/xinetd.d/oldapplication /etc/xinetd.d
```

The xinetd setup file never makes it to xinetd.d, and trying to look at the dpkg install with debug doesn't give me any hints.  The file is definitely in the tarball, it just simply never gets moved.

Looking through the different dh helper applications, I can't see anything that fits, and google does nothing to illuminate the problem.

Do I have to simply move the file over in a postinst script? Is that the only way to solve this, or is there a more "debian" way to do this by creating a file in the dpkg's debian directory?  Is there a more generic setup I should be doing to put files into /etc?

Thanks.

Comment: Would be better if you keep the info short and addressed where you got the error. What error you got when you installed your *.deb package?